# I am trying have data appear in the "Values" field in a pivot table, but the pivot table keeps summing the values that have the same date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

In the pivot table, when there are two or more values assigned to a date, they sum.

[image: Pivot Table]

I don't want the values to sum. I want each value listed, even if the date is same for the values. I've tried going to "Sum of..." dropdown > Value Fields Setting, but it only gives me other operations like "Count", "Average", "Max", "Min", "Product", etc.

[image: Value Field Settings]

Is there a way to stop the calculation and just let the values show for each date?

Comment: I think the only way to do it is to add an index on your original data. Otherwise, this can be done with powerquery.

Comment: Did you try the Power Query?

Comment: Add a column which is unique to the rows area. What is it about one value or another that tells you they are different and should not be summed? Use that. Might be customer number or some kind of transaction reference for example. You can always hide the column if you don't want to see it.